# How to manually construct an AST?

Tags: ruby, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer, ll-grammar

I'm currently learning about parsing but i'm a bit confused as how to generate an AST. I have written a parser that correctly verifies whether an expressions conforms to a grammar (it is silent when the expression conforms and raises an exception when it is not). Where do i go from here to build an AST? I  found plenty of information on building my LL(1) parser, but very little on then going on to build the AST.

My current code (written in very simple Ruby, and including a lexer and a parser) is found here on github: https://gist.github.com/e9d4081b7d3409e30a57

Can someone explain how i go from what i have currently to an AST?

Alternatively, if you are unfamiliar with Ruby, but know C, could you tell me how i build an AST for the C code in the [recursive descent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) wikipedia article.

Please note, i do not want to use a parser generator like yacc or antlr to do the work for me, i want to do everything from scratch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to associate each symbol that you match with a callback that constructs that little part of the tree.  For example, let's take a fairly common construct: nested function calls.

```
a(b())
```

Your terminal tokens here are something like:

- L_PAREN = '('
- R_PAREN = ')'
- IDENTIFIER = [a-z]+

And your nonterminal symbols are something like:

- FUNCTION_CALL = IDENTIFIER, L_PAREN, R_PAREN
- or;
- FUNCTION_CALL = IDENTIFIER, L_PAREN, FUNCTION_CALL, R_PAREN

Obviously the second alternative above for the rule `FUNCTION_CALL` is recursive.

You already have a parser that knows it has found a valid symbol.  The bit you're missing is to attach a callback to the rule, which receives its components as inputs and returns a value (usually) representing that node in the AST.

Imagine if the first alternative from our `FUNCTION_CALL` rule above had a callback:

```
Proc.new do |id_tok, l_paren_tok, r_paren_tok|
  { item: :function_call, name: id_tok, args: [] }
end
```

That would mean that the AST resulting from matching:

```
a()
```

Would be:

```
{
  item: :function_call,
  name: "a",
  args: []
}
```

Now to extrapolate that to the more complex `a(b())`.  Because the parser is recursive, it will recognize the `b()` first, the callback from which returns what we have above, but with "b" instead of "a".

Now let's define the callback attached to the rule that matches the second alternative.  It's very similar, except it also deals with the argument it was passed:

```
Proc.new do |id_tok, l_paren_tok, func_call_item, r_paren_tok|
  { item: :function_call, name: id_tok, args: [ func_call_item ] }
end
```

Because the parser has already recognized `b()` and that part of the AST was returned from your callback, the resulting tree is now:

```
{
  item: :function_call,
  name: "a",
  args: [
    {
      item: :function_call,
      name: "b",
      args: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Hopefully this gives you some food for thought.  Pass all the tokens you match into a routine that constructs very small parts of your AST.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In my travels i learned that a `parse tree` is different to an `AST` - can you tell me why what you generated here is an AST rather than a `parse tree` ? just curious :)

Comment: I've never thought of the two things as being different, actually, sorry.  If there's a difference, it's not something I've ever encountered.  Are you talking about a parse table vs. a parse tree, perhaps?

Comment: From the wikipedia page for 'Abstract Syntax Tree': "In computer science, an abstract syntax tree (AST), or just syntax tree, is a tree representation of the abstract syntactic structure of source code written in a programming language."

Comment: Ah, ok.  It sounds like a parse tree is a very "dumb" record of what rules were used to match the input throughout the parse, while an AST is more like what I constructed above, which understands that a function call has args etc.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so here I am again (and nope, this answer has nothing to do with Scintilla per se; although it WAS part of a Programming Language / Compiler Design adventure of mine, once).

Have you considered using [**Lex**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) / [**Yacc**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) ? That's what their main reason of existance is (= parsing; writing Lexers and Parsers, and thus, the way to build `AST`s), plus they are absolutely C-friendly.

---

Here's a rough example (taken from my own open-sourced [MathMachine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathmachine/) compiler).

**mm_lexer.l** (the Lexer)

```
%{
/*
MathMachine
Copyright (C) 2009-2011 Dr.Kameleon

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
*//*

MM_LEXER.L

*/

#include "mathmachine.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

void count();
%}

DIGIT           [0-9]
LETTER          [a-zA-Z_]
HEX         [a-fA-F0-9]
BINARY          [0-1]

%%
^[ \t]*"//".*\n             { /* This is a '//' single-line comment */ }
^[ \t]*"#!".*\n             { /* This is a '#!' single-line comment */ }
"use"                   { count(); return(USE); }
"set"                   { count(); return(SET); }
"let"                   { count(); return(LET); }
"ret"                   { count(); return(RET); }
"put"                   { count(); return(PUT); }
"get"                   { count(); return(GET); }
"if"                    { count(); return(IF); }
"else"                  { count(); return(ELSE); }
"loop"                  { count(); return(LOOP); }
"save"                  { count(); return(SAVE); }
"exec"                  { count(); return(EXEC); }


"true"                  { count(); return(TRUE); }
"false"                 { count(); return(FALSE); }

{LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*     { count(); return(ID); }

{DIGIT}+                { count(); return(DECIMAL);     /* DECIMAL NUMBER */}
0"h"{HEX}+              { count(); return(HEXADECIMAL); /* HEXADECIMAL NUMBER */}
0"b"{BINARY}+               { count(); return(BINARY);  /* BINARY NUMBER */}  
{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}+         { count(); return(REAL);    /* REAL NUMBER */}

\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"           { count(); return(STRING); }

"=="                    { count(); return(EQ_OP); }
"<="                    { count(); return(LE_OP); }
">="                    { count(); return(GE_OP); }
"<"                 { count(); return(LT_OP); }
">"                 { count(); return(GT_OP); }
"!="                    { count(); return(NE_OP); }

"-->"                   { count(); return(RANGE); }

"("                 { count(); return('('); }
")"                 { count(); return(')'); }
"{"                 { count(); return('{'); }
"}"                 { count(); return('}'); }
"["                 { count(); return('['); }
"]"                 { count(); return(']'); }

"-"                 { count(); return('-'); }
"+"                 { count(); return('+'); }
"*"                 { count(); return('*'); }
"/"                 { count(); return('/'); }

"="                 { count(); return('='); }
";"                 { count(); return(';'); }
","                 { count(); return(','); }
":"                 { count(); return(':'); }
"."                 { count(); return('.'); }
"?"                 { count(); return('?'); }
"%"                 { count(); return('%'); }
"&"                 { count(); return('&'); }
"$"                 { count(); return('$'); }
"#"                 { count(); return('#'); }
"@"                 { count(); return('@'); }
"|"                 { count(); return('|'); }
"!"                 { count(); return('!'); }
"~"                 { count(); return('~'); }
"^"                 { count(); return('^'); }

[ \t\v\n\f]             { count(); }
.                   { /* ignore it */ } 



%%

int yycolumn = 0;

void count()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; yytext[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (yytext[i] == '\n')
            yycolumn = 0;
        else if (yytext[i] == '\t')
            yycolumn += 8 - (yycolumn % 8);
        else
            yycolumn++;

    // ECHO;
    yylval.str=strdup(yytext);
}
```

---

**mm_parser.y** (the Parser)

```
%{
/*
MathMachine
Copyright (C) 2009-2011 Dr.Kameleon

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
*//*

MM_PARSER.Y

*/

#include "mathmachine.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\n%*s\n%*s\n", yycolumn, "^", yycolumn, str);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
%}

%union 
{
    char* str;
    mm_st_exec*         _st_exec;
    mm_st_use*          _st_use;
    mm_st_set*          _st_set;
    mm_st_ret*          _st_ret;
    mm_st_let*          _st_let;
    mm_st_get*          _st_get;
    mm_st_loop*             _st_loop;
    mm_st_if*           _st_if;
    mm_st_put*          _st_put;
    mm_st_save*         _st_save;
    mm_condition*           _condition;
    mm_argument*            _argument;
    mm_function_call*       _function_call;
    mm_expression_node*     _expression_node;
    mm_statement*           _statement;
    mm_statement_list*      _statement_list;
    mm_expression_list*     _expression_list;
    mm_id_list*         _id_list;
    comparison_operator_type    _comparison_op_type;
}

%token <str> SET LET PUT GET IF ELSE LOOP USE SAVE LOAD TIME RET EXEC
%token <str> ID DECIMAL HEXADECIMAL BINARY REAL STRING
%token <str> EQ_OP LE_OP GE_OP LT_OP GT_OP NE_OP RANGE
%token <str> TRUE FALSE

%type <str> number boolean 

%type <_comparison_op_type> comparison_operator

%type <_function_call> function_call

%type <_id_list> id_list

%type <_condition> condition
%type <_argument> argument

%type <_expression_node> expression

%type <_expression_list> expression_list

%type <_st_exec> exec_statement
%type <_st_use> use_statement
%type <_st_ret> ret_statement
%type <_st_let> let_statement
%type <_st_get> get_statement
%type <_st_loop> loop_statement
%type <_st_if> if_statement
%type <_st_put> put_statement
%type <_st_set> set_statement
%type <_st_save> save_statement

%type <_statement> statement

%type <_statement_list> statement_list block main

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%expect 11

%start main

%%

//---------------------------
// The Basic Elements
//---------------------------

number
    :   DECIMAL     { $$ = $1; }                
    |   HEXADECIMAL { $$ = $1; }            
    |   BINARY      { $$ = $1; }            
    |   REAL        { $$ = $1; }            
    ;

boolean
    :   TRUE        { $$ = $1; }
    |   FALSE       { $$ = $1; }
    ;

function_call
    :   ID '(' ')'          { $$ = new mm_function_call($1,NULL); }
    |   ID '(' expression_list ')'  { $$ = new mm_function_call($1,$3); }
    ;

argument
    :   number      { $$ = new mm_argument($1,number); }
    |   STRING      { $$ = new mm_argument($1,alpha); }
    |   boolean     { $$ = new mm_argument($1,boolean); }
    |   function_call   { $$ = new mm_argument($1,function); }
    |   ID      { $$ = new mm_argument($1,variable); }  
    ;

comparison_operator
    :   EQ_OP       { $$ = eq_operator; }
    |   LT_OP       { $$ = lt_operator; }
    |   GT_OP       { $$ = gt_operator; }
    |   LE_OP       { $$ = le_operator; }
    |   GE_OP       { $$ = ge_operator; }
    |   NE_OP       { $$ = ne_operator; }
    ;

//---------------------------
// The Building Blocks
//---------------------------

id_list
    :   ID              { $$ = new mm_id_list(); 
                          $$->addId($1); }                      
    |   id_list ',' ID          { $1->addId($3); $$=$1; }
    ;

expression
    :   argument                    { $$ = new mm_expression_node($1);  }
    |   '(' expression ')'              { $$ = $2;  }
    |   expression '+' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"+",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   expression '-' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"-",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   expression '*' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"*",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   expression '/' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"/",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   expression '%' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"%",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   expression '^' expression           { $$ = new mm_expression_node(new mm_argument((char*)"^",oper),$1,$3,operator_node); }
    |   '-' argument %prec UMINUS           {  }
    ;

expression_list
    :   expression              { $$ = new mm_expression_list(); 
                              $$->addExpression(new mm_expression($1)); }                       
    |   expression_list ',' expression      { $1->addExpression(new mm_expression($3)); $$=$1; }
    ;

condition
    :   expression                  { $$ = new mm_condition(new mm_expression($1),empty_operator,NULL); }
    |   expression comparison_operator expression       { $$ = new mm_condition(new mm_expression($1), $2, new mm_expression($3)); }
    ;

//---------------------------
// The Statements
//---------------------------

exec_statement
    :   EXEC STRING ';'             { $$ = new mm_st_exec($2); }
    ;

use_statement
    :   USE STRING ';'              { $$ = new mm_st_use($2); /*printf("USE statement : %s\n",$2);*/ }
    ;

set_statement
    :   SET ID '(' id_list ')' '=' expression ';'   { 
                                    mm_st_ret* rt = new mm_st_ret(new mm_expression($7));
                                    mm_statement_list* stlist = new mm_statement_list();
                                    mm_statement* st = new mm_statement(ret_statement,rt);
                                    stlist->addStatement(*st);
                                    $$ = new mm_st_set($2,$4,stlist); 
                                }
    |   SET ID '(' id_list ')' '=' block        { $$ = new mm_st_set($2,$4,$7); }
    ;

let_statement
    :   LET ID '=' expression ';'           { $$ = new mm_st_let($2,new mm_expression($4)); }
    ;

get_statement
    :   GET ID ';'                  { $$ = new mm_st_get($2); }
    ;

ret_statement
    :   RET expression ';'              { $$ = new mm_st_ret(new mm_expression($2)); }
    ;

put_statement
    :   PUT expression_list ';'             { $$ = new mm_st_put($2); }
    ;

if_statement
    :   IF '(' condition ')' block          { $$ = new mm_st_if($3,$5,NULL); }
    |   IF '(' condition ')' block ELSE block       { $$ = new mm_st_if($3,$5,$7); }
    ;

loop_statement
    :   LOOP '(' condition ')' block            { $$ = new mm_st_loop($3,$5); }
    ;

save_statement
    :   SAVE expression_list '@' STRING ';'     { $$ = new mm_st_save($2,$4); }
    ;

statement
    :   exec_statement              { $$ = new mm_statement(exec_statement,$1); }
    |   use_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(use_statement,$1); }
    |   set_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(set_statement,$1); }
    |   let_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(let_statement,$1); }
    |   get_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(get_statement,$1); }
    |   ret_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(ret_statement,$1); }
    |   put_statement               { $$ = new mm_statement(put_statement,$1); }
    |   if_statement                { $$ = new mm_statement(if_statement,$1); }
    |   loop_statement              { $$ = new mm_statement(loop_statement,$1); }
    |   save_statement              { $$ = new mm_statement(save_statement,$1); }
    ;

//---------------------------
// The Main Loop
//---------------------------

statement_list
    :   statement               { $$ = new mm_statement_list(); $$->addStatement(*$1); }
    |   statement_list statement        { $1->addStatement(*$2); $$ = $1; }
    ;

block 
    :   '{' statement_list '}'          { $$ = $2; }
    ;

main
    :   statement_list              { Base->Statements = $1; }
    ;

%%
```

---

***Sidenote :** Unfortunately, I can't help you with anything Ruby-specific (since I'm not only an absolute newbie, but actually - for some unknown reason - I hate it); but, even in C, I hope this'll give you a rough idea... :-)*

Comment: I think you completely miss the point here. This is what the OP stated at the end of the question : `Please note, i do not want to use a parser generator like yacc or antlr to do the work for me, i want to do everything from scratch.`